# SharePoint Silverlight Image viewer (AG_E_Network_Error)

Tags: silverlight-3.0, imaging

My application is a Silverlight Image viewer that displays images from Sharepoint using the Silverlight Image control (by setting the source propery). My app displays the first image and i can use navigation buttons to go forward and backward.

Everything is working fine, however after a certain amount of images (always the same amout for the same folder (probably when reaching the same download limit) i start getting the AG_E_Network_Error and the images can no more get loaded.

I can then no longer display any image (always the same error) until i refresh the application.

Any help pleaaaaase? any limit on downloading in a silverlight app?

Guys, please Help, it's urgent...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't destroying my images when they weren't showing anymore, this was killing the RAM, on every load the RAM usage was getting higher and higher untill images can no more be loaded (AG_NETWORK_ERROR).
Just set image source = null for every previous image, and i was fine.